# SSL errors with QtWebkit on https sites on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ssl, webkit, qtwebkit, libssl

I am building a qtwebkit-based browser application on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I use it to access https websites, I got a lot of ssl errors. For example, when I access www.paypal.com, I got this message:

SSL Errors for: https://t.paypal.com/ts?v=0.1&t=1341683749338&g=420&e=im&pgrp=main%3Amktg%3Apersonal%3A%3Ahome&page=main%3Amktg%3Apersonal%3A%3Ahome%3A%3A%3ANotInTest%3B

The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose
No certificates could be verified

I am using QtSDK 4.8.1. The application is linked to libssl 0.9.8. Although ubuntu comes with libssl 1.0, the prebuilt version of QtSDK 4.8.1 is linked to 0.9.8. So I have to install libssl 0.9.8 to get it to work.

The same application works fine on windows and mac.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please share with me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to another StackOverflow question which I think has the solution to your problems: [Is this the right way to set the SSL protocol with QWebPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941630/is-this-the-right-way-to-set-the-ssl-protocol-with-qwebpage)

Also, this thread: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19690 on the qt forums talks about the exact same issues that you have been experiencing.